# Smooth traversal of ()

Tags: smooth-manifolds, machine-learning, orthogonal-matrices

I am trying to constrain the space of matrices used for the layers of a neural network to those in ().  [It is proven that () is a manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124237/the-special-orthogonal-group-is-a-manifold).  I'm trying to find a way to smoothly traverse this manifold.

Note this is a bit different than just sampling () using something like Graham-Schmidt.  The function used to construct a matrix would need to be, and ideally run in linear time rather than the cubic time needed for Graham-Schmidt.  The sampling of () would not need to be uniform.

I believe I read a post here before that had a function for constructing said matrices, but I haven't been able to find it again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not requiring a uniform or other distribution leaves too much freedom, such as selecting the same matrix all the time.

Comment: @Ruy it's okay to always start at the same initial point, so long as I can traverse the manifold from the starting point.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "traversing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are looking for a parametrization of $SO(n)$ that you can then perhaps also use for optimization procedures. Such a method has, for example, been discussed [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.08428v2.pdf). I am not an expert on this, but essentially we can use the exponential map
$$\exp(A) := I + A + \frac{A^2}{2} + \dots 
$$
to translate an optimization problem over a compact group such as $SO(n)$ into a problem over the space of skew-symmetric matrices. The latter can be parametrized more easily (see the paper for details).

Comment: Small comment: The exponential map of a Lie group is not in general surjective, but it is surjective for the group $SO(n)$.

Comment: Thank you!  The exponent of a skew-symmetric matrix was indeed what I was looking for.  Thanks as well for helping bridge some of the terminology.